# In Python's string.format what is the equivalent to %r?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, formatting

I'm used to using `%r` in [string formatting using the `%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), but how do I use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatspec) method for the same result?

```
>>> x = 1 + 1e-14
>>> x
1.00000000000001
>>> '%r' % x
'1.00000000000001'
>>> '{0}'.format(x)
'1.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, missed it in the docs on first read; it's the `!r` conversion. (see [examples section in docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-examples))

```
>>> '{0!r}'.format(x)
'1.00000000000001'
```